# Python error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4, but it is?

Tags: python, unicode, struct

I'm using python 2.7. I don't understand why this doesn't work, could someone please give me a hint.

```
>>> from struct import unpack
>>> T2 = u'\xb6'+u'\x01'+u'\x59'+u'\x59'
>>> T2
u'\xb6\x01YY'
>>> unpack('i', TS)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

I thought I'm putting in a string argument of 4?

The reason I'm using unicode is that I'm trying to extract the data from this URL i'm being sent:

```
path="/write/?type=stxetx&packet=AX%05YX%01%00%00%00%00%00%00%02%00%A0%00%05%00%C8%00%C0%0D%28%28%00%00%E85&localpackettime=2016-12-20+09%3A18%3A57&serial=868324023356343&packettime=2016-12-20+09%3A18%3A57&receivetime=2016-12-20+09%3A18%3A58&timezone=UTC"
```

This is the code I use to get the packet data:

```
packet_data = request.GET.getlist('packet')                                                                                                                                                                   
     data_list = list(packet_data[0])                                                                                                                                                                              
     print "Data list ",data_list
```

This gives me a unicode list like the following:

```
>> Data list  [u'A', u'v', u'\x05', u'Y', u'X', u'\x01', u'\x00', u'\x00', u'\x00', u'\x00', u'\x00', u'\x00', u'\x02', u'\x00', u'\xa0', u'\x00', u'\x05', u'\x00', u'\xc8', u'\x00', u'\xc0', u'\r', u'(', u'(', u'\x00', u'\x00', u'\xe8', u'5']
```

`data_list[1:5]` make up a 4 byte int timestamp and the only way had that working at one point was to unpack the values however it throws this error.

Should I be decoding/encoding the unicode before unpacking?

Comment: Why do you have a Unicode string in the first place? That's not text, that's binary data you have.

Comment: Note that python3 clarifies this error message: `a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`.

Comment: I've asked my question properly as a new question as it's now confusing, thanks for your help - [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246696/how-to-unpack-stxetx-data-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unpack Unicode text. You'd unpack *binary data*. The error tells you that you passed in the wrong object type. You'd get the same error if you passed in an *empty* Unicode string:

```
>>> struct.unpack('i', u'')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

Don't use Unicode:

```
>>> struct.unpack('i', '\xb6\x01YY')
(1499005366,)
```

Comment: What indicates that it's binary?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: In Python 2, the default `str` type is a binary string.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: and if you want to interpret data as in integer, it is not text. It is binary data. Text doesn't encode a 4-byte signed integer value in 4 bytes.

Comment: And the default format is "utf-8". So the packing and unpacking of binary data is done with 'utf-8'?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: UTF-8 is a codec, not a format. And what does that have to do with `struct.unpack()`?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: and UTF-8 is not a default in Python 2. Are you talking about the Python 3 source code default codec? Or the JSON default encoding? Or the default console encoding for Windows in Python 3.6 or up? In what *context* is UTF-8 a default?

Comment: Watched Ned's video on codecs. I still need to learn more on codecs and maybe my understanding is flawed. But this is what I can recollect from that video that Python2.7 does operation in utf-8. Anyways if you can just point me to some good resource that would be great.

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi: no, Python 2.7 operates in Latin-1 by default, and implicit encoding and decoding when mixing Unicode and bytestrings is done in ASCII. I think you have things confused with Python 3. At any rate, this question is not dealing with textual data, it is dealing with the [C struct format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)), which lets you share data across networks or files in a specific binary format.